# How to verify array response values in postman test?

Tags: postman

Expected Test Scenario: **Need to validate the array response "Values" for the "Key: id".**

I am using the test code:

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.contains(16);
});
```

Getting the error:
AssertionError: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but undefined given.

Response Body:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Name": "Hello",
        "Country": "India"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "Name": "thankyou",
        "Country": "UK"
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "Name": "how are you",
        "Country": "USA"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "Name": "Good morning",
        "Country": "Italy"
    },
    {
        "id": 25510,
        "Name": "Bonjour",
        "Country": "France"
    }
]
```

Anyone could help me in sorting out this please.

Answer (score -1):

The response is not a JSON object but JSON array.

pm.response.json() will have you full json which is in the form :

[ {}, {} ]

so the JSON object with id 16 is the 3rd element in the array so first call jsonData[3] and then get id in it.

But still you will get error because what you are getting is a "integer" so cannot use contains with it . Use equal instead

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(jsonData[2].id).to.equal(16);
});
```

or if you want to use contains instead , then get response as text using pm.response.text():

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.text();

pm.expect(jsonData).to.contains(16);
});
```

Comment: I think OP is asking if he can search for that value within all of them, as they would not know what object actually has that ID